# Best way to subset RNAseq dataset for comparison in R

Tags: r

I have a single-cell RNAseq dataset that I have been using R to analyze. So I have a data frame with 205 columns and 15000 rows. Each column is a cell and each row is a gene.

I have an annotation matrix that has the identity of each cell. For example, patient ID, disease status, etc...

I want to do different comparisons based on the grouping info provided by the annotation matrix.

I know that in python, you can create a dictionary that is attached to the cell IDs.

What is an efficient way in R to perform subsetting of the same dataset in different ways?

So far what I have been doing is:

```
EC_index <-subset(annotation_index_LN, conditions == "EC_LN")
CP_index <-subset(annotation_index_LN, conditions =="CP_LN")

CD69pos <-subset(annotation_index_LN, CD69 == 100)
EC_CD69pos <- subset(EC_index, CD69 == 100)
EC_CD69pos <- subset(EC_CD69pos, id %in% colnames(manual_normalized))
CP_CD69pos <- subset(CP_index, CD69 == 100)
CP_CD69pos <- subset(CP_CD69pos, id %in% colnames(manual_normalized))
```

Comment: I believe you are not using `id %in% colnames(manual_normalized)` correctly.  1.If you want to selected columns using the `subset` function, then you have use the select argument.  2. It is not likely to select the desired columns. Try `select = colnames(manual_normalized) %in% id`.

Comment: 15k rows and 200 columns is not such a huge data set. Almost any approach will be efficient enough. What I would do is transpose the gene data so genes are columns and cells are rows and do a left join with the annotation matrix. This is how most functions like their data since genes are features and cell types are subjects. With one call to subset/filter you can filter out based on cell or annotation. I would also try not to make too many subseted objects in the environment, but rather use %>% and pass the subsets directly to plot or statistical functions.

Comment: Just a quick question: I am a bit confused on why you think I am not using id %in% colnames(manual_normalized) correctly. Do you mind clarify it a bit further? The purpose of this line is to make sure that the id in my EC_CD69pos matches with the IDs present in the dataset. I wasn't trying to subset the data the main dataset (aka manual_normalized)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't entirely answer your question, but I think that even before you begin trying to subset your data etc. you might want to think about converting this into a `SummarizedExperiment`. This is a type of object that can hold annotation data for features and samples and will keep everything properly referenced if you decide to subset samples, remove rows, etc. This type of object is commonly implemented by packages hosted on Bioconductor. They have loads of tutorials on various genomics pipelines, and I'm sure you can find more detailed information there.

http://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/

Answer (score 0):

Following is from the `iris` data in R since you haven't given a minimal example of your data.

For that you need a R package that gives access to `%>%`: the `magrittr` R package, but also available in `dplyr`.

If you have to a lot of subsetting, the have the following in a function where you pass the arguments to subset.

```
iris %>% 
  subset(Species == "setosa" & Petal.Width == 0.2 & Petal.Length == 1.4) %>% 
  subset(select = !is.na(str_match(colnames(iris), "Len")))

#         Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1           5.1          1.4
# 2           4.9          1.4
# 5           5.0          1.4
# 9           4.4          1.4
# 29          5.2          1.4
# 34          5.5          1.4
# 48          4.6          1.4
# 50          5.0          1.4
```